# Bokeh plots not showing in nbviewer

Tags: python, plot, jupyter, bokeh

I am working on some visualizations using Bokeh in a Jupyter (ipython) notebook. Though the plots run well within my notebook, it is important for me to make them accessible for users not running the code. I was counting on nbviewer for this, but am having trouble.

Using a simple plot for example, I get this great output in my running notebook:

[Running notebook in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyJwF.png)

After pushing to github I view the notebook in nbviewer but my plots are gone: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/kaplann/bokeh_trouble/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/bokeh%20error-checkpoint.ipynb

I am using chrome Version 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit) on fedora 23, Bokeh - 0.12.1, 
Python 3.5.1, Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit),  IPython - 5.1.0

I have a very strong feeling I am missing something, hopefully I am and the fix will be simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notebook is an extremely difficult and challenging environment to develop and test Bokeh for. There have been some recent regressions and work to fix them, please refer to GitHub issues [#5014](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5014) and [#5081](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5081) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you recommend any other possible solutions in the meantime? Perhaps saving an html version and embedding in in the notebook or some other kind of workaround/hack?

Comment: Please try `0.12.2` released yesterday.